# Django: Passing a queryset to another view with HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django

In an admin.py I have setup an action called export as you can see below...

```
class RecipientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [export]
export.short_description = "Export Stuff"
admin.site.register(Recipient, RecipientAdmin)
```

This runs the following function...

```
def export(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/export/")
```

My question is...

How can I pass the queryset to another  view/page it is possible using HttpResponseRedirect? or is there another way I should try to do this?

**I want the records that have been preselected on the list view to be carried to the new page so I can iterate over them.**

Comment: why do a redirect at all? is it possible to just call the view behind `/export/` from the function `export()`?

Comment: I want a intermediate confirm page with additional options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

1> If all you want do is filter by some fields in the model then you can pass the filters in url. Example: '/export/?id_*gte=3&status*_exact=3'

2> In your export action function you can set some variable or entire queryset in session and then check for it in you export view

```
def export(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    """
    not sure if this will work
    """
    request.session['export_querset'] = queryset

    """
    if above does not work then just set this and check for it in view and u can make the queryset again if this is set 
    """
    request.session['export_querset'] = 1
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/export/")
```

Comment: filter i don't think will work as i want the records that have been preselected on the list view to be carried to the new page so i can iterate over them.

Comment: then probably u can set the queryset in session, how about that