# How to get data that was displayed in template with django template language into different method

Tags: python, html, django

How can i access data, after i press button, that was displayed in my template from different method in views.py. Short example of what i am trying to achieve:

**TEMPLATE: (test.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  {% for each in my_list %}
   <p>each</p>
  {% endfor %}
<a class="btn" href="url to cal second_method"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Views.py:**

```
def first_method(request, template='test.html'):
   context = {
      'my_list': ["one","two","tree"]
   }

   return render(
       request,
       template,
       context
   )

def second_method(request):
# i want to work with my_list here after pressing <a>
# i want to be able to export it to excel for example
```

What is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by cashing the query set. See: [Django cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could store your queryset in a session and than retrieve it in another view. See [Django: Passing a queryset to another view with HttpResponseRedirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323467/django-passing-a-queryset-to-another-view-with-httpresponseredirect) for some hints.

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you think there is any other option, maybe with javascript or is session the only option, also do you know how it will work with very large queryset?

Comment: I would definitely stick with Django and session possibility if it is doable. I don't see the benefit of implementing another language if it isn't necessary. I can't comment on large querysets, because I don't have experiences with such querysets and I also don't know what is the limit to define a queryset as large. But I believe that this info can be found easily.